# Fast VLC (and/or libvlc) frame Extraction

Tags: video, performance, vlc, libvlc

I want to extract all frames from VLC the fastest way possible. What I have currently is:

```
vlc movie.flv --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --aout=dummy \
              --scene-format=jpeg --scene-ratio=1 --scene-prefix=img \
              --scene-path=./images/ vlc://quit
```

This commands opens a VLC player and plays a headless video, so to extract all frames the video should be played till the end!

I know that I can use FFmpeg, I've tried it and it's extrememly fast, but I need VLC!
Any libvlc workarounds are accepted.

Comment: Why must it be VLC? AFAIK VLC just wraps ffmpeg.